# How do I cast an object to a new instance of an object on one line? C#

Tags: c#, syntax, casting

Basically just want to turn this

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(COMPUTER));

COMPUTER computers = (COMPUTER)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(Properties.Resources.computerXML));
```

into one line. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you writing in Basic or C# ? Review your code.

Comment: Definitely C#, what made you think it was Basic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't understand your need to get this done in one, ugly line...

```
var computers = new XmlSerializer(typeof(COMPUTER)).Deserialize(new StringReader(Properties.Resources.computerXML));
```

BTW, you're leaking your `StringReader`, so to do this properly no, you can't have it in one line.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(COMPUTER));
using (var reader = new StringReader(Properties.Resources.computerXML))
{
    var computers = (COMPUTER)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Really I just wanted to understand the syntax and see what I was doing wrong.